# Will a 'JavaScriptResult' return to an 'eval' in MVC and effect site performance?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I was looking up some ways to redirect from an ajax request and came across a solution:

```
return JavaScript("window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'");
```

I was told that this might get wrapped in an eval upon its return, which can change how the code is compiled and effect efficiency.

```
eval("window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'"); //actually gets executed
```

I was told to change it to just return the redirect url.

Two questions about this:

1) Would executing an `eval`, in a 'success' through an ajax request, effect the compilation of other javascript?

2) What happens when I return from my post with a `JavaScript` `ActionResult`? Does it eventually run inside an `eval` (implicitly)?

```
// In MVC Controller
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    return JsonResult("window.location = 'url'");
}

// In javascript
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/MyAction'
});
```

Comment: you don't need eval here, at all... it won't slow anything down or change the way the url instantly navigates...

Comment: @dandavis Will it implicitly use eval?

Comment: my point is just that `eval("window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk'");` does the same thing as `window.location = 'http://www.google.co.uk';`, if that's the code going to the browser were talking about here...

Comment: Right. I'm double checking that the compiler will still optimize. I suppose it would only see the `eval` when we return from the request so who cares how optimized that code is since its one line.

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScriptResult` simply returns JavaScript to the client, so you can, for instance, access it from a `<script>` element:

```
<script src="/MyCoolController/GiveMeScript?param5=7"></script>
```

How that JavaScript gets executed is up to you.

I don't really see why the performance of `eval()` would be a concern if your objective is to redirect the page, but this sounds like a pretty questionable approach to (especially if it involves `eval()`).

Why not just return a JsonResult that indicates a redirect using some pre-decided convention, and then have your script act accordingly:

```
// in controller
return JsonResult(new { redirectTo = "http://www.google.co.uk" });
```

```
// in script
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '...',
    success: function (result) {
        if (result.redirectTo) {
            window.location = result.redirectTo;
        }
        // handle result if not redirecting ...
    }
});
```

Comment: I am doing something similar by using `return Content("http://www.google.co.uk");`. I think using `JavaScript` is fine though.